# Wait for the countdown timer to finish or the user to click a button

Tags: android, timer

I'm trying to create a mini-game loop in which the user has 10 seconds to click a button or loses the game.  When I run the while game loop, I want the while loop to start the timer and then either wait for the timer to run out or the user to click a button.  Also, when the code runs, the app crashes within the while loop.  Not sure how to continue.

I'm rather new to android.
Thanks in advance.

```
public class MainGame extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

ProgressBar progress1;

Boolean gameon = true;

Button option1;
Button option2;
Button option3;

private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
private final long startTime = 10*1000;
private final long interval= 100;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_game);

                    Log.d("Mark", "justCreated Completed");

    initializebuttons();//also initializes timer, buttons, text, etc.
                    Log.d("Mark", "Initialize Buttons Function Completed");
    maingameloop();




    //Drawable draw = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_progress_bar);
    //progress1.setProgressDrawable(draw);
}


private void initializebuttons(){

    option1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonchoice1);
    option1.setOnClickListener(this);
    option2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonchoice2);
    option2.setOnClickListener(this);
    option3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonchoice3);
    option3.setOnClickListener(this);

    countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer (startTime, interval);

    Log.d("Mark", "Inside the initialize buttons function");

}

private void maingameloop(){
    while (gameon){

        Log.d("Mark", "while loop running");
        countDownTimer.start();

    }
}

public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
    public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval){
        super (startTime, interval);
        synchronized(this){

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        option1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.LightGreen));

    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){

    case R.id.buttonchoice1:
        break;
    case R.id.buttonchoice2:
        break;
    case R.id.buttonchoice3:

    default:
        break;

    }


}


}
```

Comment: What *exactly* are you stuck on?

Comment: I've attempted and don't know how to make the while loop wait and listen for a user click.

Comment: Oh good Lord. Whats happening in `while (gameon)`. Just start the timer once and when its finished do something and if user presses button, cancel the timer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I get what you are saying, and if so, try doing this

instead of initializeButtons(), do

```
countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer (startTime, interval);
countDownTimer.start();
```

and then in onStart() of your CountDownTimer call initializeButtons();

```
private void initializebuttons(){

    option1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonchoice1);
    option1.setOnClickListener(this);
    option2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonchoice2);
    option2.setOnClickListener(this);
    option3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonchoice3);
    option3.setOnClickListener(this);

    Log.d("Mark", "Inside the initialize buttons function");

}
```

in onClick(View v), assuming that the answer and the text of the button are the same

```
if(v.getText().toString().equals(answer)){
     // do what you would do if you win
     win = true;               // win is a private class boolean I've created for you
     countDownTimer.cancel();
}
```

and then in onFinish()

```
if(!win){
   // do what you want for a loss
}
```

This will make it so that you determine if a button is clicked within the limit. If so you win, if not you lose. This isn't exactly based on your code, but can be modified to work.

Comment: Kind of...I want there to be a timer and the user has to click on the correct answer in the allotted amount of time.  But if the timer is up, it kicks you out of the while loop. When debugging the posted code, the app crashes.

Comment: @user2766546 check my edits. Something like that should work for what you need

Answer (score 0):

With this

```
 while (gameon){

    Log.d("Mark", "while loop running");
    countDownTimer.start();

}
```

you will run the code

```
countDownTimer.start();
```

with every iteration which I'm sure **is not** what you want. You don't need (want?) this `while loop` at all. Simply start the timer whenever you need then in `onFinish()` run the code that you want to run when time runs out and place this code in the `Button` click as well. Obviously you could put this all in one function and call that function from `onFinish()` and `onClick()` or whatever.

I would also suggest checking in `onClick()`, or the method which runs the code, to cancel the timer and initialize it to `null`.